# PostgreSQL: is there a way to do an UPDATE in case DELETE fails due tue a foreign key?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm wondering if there is something like "ON CONFLICT", that works for DELETE.

My situation is like this: I need to update the flag "active" to FALSE when I try to DELETE a row that fails because there is a foreign key on another table.

I need a generic way to check if any FK exists, as in the future there will be more tables having a FK that point to the table where I'm trying to do this.

Thank you! :)

Comment: No, you'll have to do that on foot.

Comment: Could you maybe put this query in a function and then when a `foreign_key_violation` exception occurs catch it and do your `update`?

Comment: What I mean is something like this https://dbfiddle.uk/HBKU1Q51

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second part of your question, you can get all the foreign keys of your database with this query

```
SELECT c.conrelid::regclass AS table,
   string_agg(a.attname, ',' ORDER BY x.n) AS columns,
   c.conname AS constraint,
   c.confrelid::regclass AS referenced_table
FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint c
CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(c.conkey) WITH ORDINALITY AS x(attnum, n)
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_attribute a ON (a.attnum = x.attnum AND a.attrelid = c.conrelid)
AND c.contype = 'f'
GROUP BY c.conrelid, c.conname, c.confrelid
ORDER BY pg_catalog.pg_relation_size(c.conrelid) DESC;
```

You will get the table name, the FK column name, the index name and the referenced table.